# Tensorflow filling up memory

Tags: linux, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am logging tensorboard data on an ubuntu server. All of a sudden I getting errors like
`-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device` 
from running `cd` and hitting tab in the terminal. It seems like the logs in tensorflow has filled up the disk space.

How to I make tensorflow not fill up my memory?

running: `$ df -h`

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             30G     0   30G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.0G  8.9M  6.0G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       73G   73G     0 100% /
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           6.0G     0  6.0G   0% /run/user/1000`

Answer (score 0):

tmp folder is default log directory for tensorflow, you can change to any folder I am posting sample code try this.

```
summary_directory=os.path.abspath("yourlog_dir")
train_summary_dir = os.path.join(summary_directory, "train")
test_summary_dir = os.path.join(summary_directory, "test")
train_summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(train_summary_dir, sess.graph)
train_summary_writer.add_summary(train_summaries, step)
```

Comment: Hey! I figured out the issue. Apparently the problem wasn't the location of the tensorboard logging at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the problem wasn't tensorboard at all. I turns out my model checkpoints were taking up about 3GB each. To locate the files taking up space I ran this command:

```
sudo du -x -h / | sort -h | tail -40
```